# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drug_name' (class attribute)

Tags: python, class, typeerror

```
class Prescription:
    def __init__(self, patient, drug_name, quantity):
        self.patient = patient
        self.drug_name = drug_name
        self.quantity = quantity

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Prescription(\'' + self.patient + '\', \'' + self.drug_name + 
        '\', ' + \
        str(self.quantity) + ')'
```

And in a separate file I have:

```
from lab10_classes import Pharmacy, Prescription


def batch_dispense(pharmacy, prescriptions):
    total_cost = 0
    if len(prescriptions) == 0:
        return 0
    for i in prescriptions:
        name = i.drug_name
        if name not in pharmacy.inventory:
            continue
        elif name in pharmacy.inventory:
            if pharmacy.inventory[name] > i.quantity:
                pharmacy.inventory[name] = pharmacy.inventory[name] - 
                prescriptions.quantity
                total_cost += pharmacy.unit_prices * prescriptions.quantity
    return total_cost and pharmacy


Print([Prescription('Mack', 'Zocor', -27), Prescription('Rachael', 'Crestor', 
      474), Prescription('Janet', 'Adderall', 60)])
```

In the current lab I'm working on, one of my function parameter is called 'prescriptions' and it takes a list of Prescription objects such as the print statement above. However, I keep getting:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drug_name'

Theoretically, my prescriptions parameter should be valid since it has a list of instance class objects for the Prescriptions class.

Comment: `prescriptions` is a `list`.  You will need to iterate on it to get a single prescription.

Comment: Wow. I am number 1 idiot. I was stuck for hours trying to figure why it was giving me that error. Thank you professor.